# Товарная корзина с помощью DI и Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь реализовать Интернет магазин с помощью принципа IoC. В моем решении 3 проекта, SFZ.Data - реализует слой DAL, SFZ.Services - реализует слой BLL, SFZ.WebUI - непосредственно MVC приложение. Мне необходимо реализовать корзину товаров, которая будет работать на клиенте, т.е. с помощью HttpContext.Session.

Я подсмотрел в книге Адама Фримана "ASP .NET MVC 4 Framework с примерами для профессионалом" реализацию корзины с помощью ModelBinding.

Связыватель моделей

```
public class CartModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private const string sessionKey = "Cart";

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];

        if (cart != null) return cart;

        cart = new Cart();
        controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = cart;

        return cart;
    }
}
```

Но такая реализация не подходит, так как нарушается принцип IoC, а также если необходимо будет расширить функционал корзины, например хранить её еще и в БД для ведения какой-либо статистики.

Я пробовал сделать DR:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    ...

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    ...

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    ...

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        kernel.Bind<ICartService>().To<CartService>();
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
 DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver());    
 ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ICartService), new CartModelBinder(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ICartService>()));
```

```
public class CartModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private const string sessionKey = "Cart";
    private ICartService cartService;

    public CartModelBinder(ICartService cartService)
    {
        this.cartService = cartService;
    }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        cartService = (ICartService)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];

        if (cartService != null) return cartService;

        //cart = new Cart();
        controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = cartService;

        return cartService;
    }
}
```

При вызове ICartService в контроллере, он оказывается пустым (NullReferenceExcept)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать эту затею.

P.S. Выводить HttpContext.Session в слой BLL, также нарушит принцип IoC

Answer (score 2):

Уф :( Я просто не создавал экземпляр своего сервиса.

```
cartService = new CartService();
```

Прошу прощения :(

Если возможно, подскажите, пожалуйста, правильна ли такая реализация? Работать, то работает

Comment: Если тесты есть  - то реализация правильная :)

Comment: Тесты есть, но пока только самого сервиса (не в контроллере). Не проверил добавление/удаление, т.к. не могу разобраться (документацию по moq не найду) как с помощью moq получить коллекцию товаров, предварительно вызвав void метод.

Comment: А всё же, принцип IoC я не нарушаю? Я же создаю из интерфейса экземпляр реализуемого класса. Это же сильное связывание, что не совместимо с IoC